# How can I use a sound file present in the documents directory for a local notification?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch

Within my iOS application, how can I play a sound file stored in the application's documents directory for a local notification, rather than one inside the application bundle?

I've seen a couple of applications on the App Store do this, and I was wondering how this is possible.

Answer (score 6):

It is actually possible to play a custom sound in a local notification that isn't in the app's main bundle (NSBundle).

The sound has to be stored in the `Library/Sounds` directory, for example:
 `/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/DD7E6BA0-2FC0-4DE0-95BF-C2E9C9A94E08/Library/Sounds/mySound.caf`

When you reference the sound file in the UILocalNotification `soundName` property, you simply write the filename, rather than the full directory path:

```
alert.soundName = @"mySound.caf";
```

Tested and working on iOS9.3.5. I haven't tried on other iOS versions yet.

**Footnote:**

I happened to find this information when searching the Apple Documentation regarding Remote Notifications [Here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/TheNotificationPayload.html) - Specifically, the 'Payload Keys' section, where it mentions sound.

Apple's documentation for Local & Remote Notifications ([Here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/IPhoneOSClientImp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH103-SW6)) also mentions that the sound files can be utilised if they are in the app's main bundle OR the data container:

> To play a sound, assign a sound to the soundName property. You can assign the filename of a nonlocalized custom sound in the app’s main bundle (or data container) or you can assign UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName to get the default system sound. A sound should always accompany the display of an alert message or the badging of an icon; a sound should not be played in the absence of other notification types.

Comment: @RasmusHöglund could you please explain how could you get this working  . I tried copying a file from bundle to Library/Sounds then assigned the file name to local notification  and it didn't  work . It works the normal way thought if file in bundle.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Here is the full path after moving file to library/sounds directory : file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/8A83AC24-6029-498B-9386-AB815FA4691E/Library/Sounds/notification.caf

Comment: @IsPha, once you've moved the sound file to `Library/Sounds`, you should be able to just reference it as usual in the `alert.soundName` property. What do you mean by `It works the normal way thought if file in bundle`? Did you delete the file from the NSBundle?

Comment: Thanks Andy for your replay . Actually it all works fine now except when running the app from Xcode it stops . But after restarting device it all works fine again . I think that running app from Xcode is someway similar to force quitting the app via app switcher in the way how it impacts the behavior of the app which requires restarting device to get everything back to work normally. But this is not a problem cause user will install app from AppStore which means all scenarios like my case or like silent push notification are supposed to be working fine . Thanks again for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

No you can not play an audio file that is not in the bundle and you can not modify the application bundle at runtime. One reason why Apple requires all sounds for local notifications to be bundled with the application may be for security reasons, that would make it possible for all bundled files to be checked for security risks during the review process.

Answer (score 0):

Exactly .....

```
    You can not play audio file stored in document directory for alarm as a local push notification.
```

I also had gone through various apps on app store .those apps basically look like playing customise audio from document directory for local push notification but it is not .insted it using push notification and when notification come at that time when we click on view button of that notification the app which generated the local push notification will get invoked and finally the selected audio file get played .

In this way the app is look like customized push notification using customized audio file from document directory

Comment: There is this app called "AidaReminder" it plays user's recorded audio when the local notification appears no need to access the app.

Answer (score 0):

### Support iOS 10 and above

Since iOS 10, you can use `UNMutableNotificationContent` with custom sound, even it is not in main application bundle. Here are steps

1. Add the sound file in your custom bundle, in my case it's "watch_me_request_notification.wav" in dynamic Test.Framework

[image]

2. Register sound file into `/Library/Sounds` (reference: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unnotificationsound/1649031-soundnamed)

   ```
    let libraryDirectory = FileManager.default.urls(for: .libraryDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0]
    let soundDirectory = libraryDirectory.appendingPathComponent("Sounds")

    do {
        try? FileManager.default.createDirectory(atPath: soundDirectory.path,
                                                 withIntermediateDirectories: true,
                                                 attributes: nil)

        let destFile = soundDirectory.appendingPathComponent("watch_me_request_notification.wav")

        if let sourceFile = Bundle(for: type(of: self)).url(forResource: "watch_me_request_notification", withExtension: "wav") {
            try FileManager.default.copyItem(at: sourceFile, to: destFile)
        }
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
   ```
3. Register custom sound in `UNMutableNotificationContent` when you create in-app notification

   ```
    let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    content.sound = UNNotificationSound(named: UNNotificationSoundName("watch_me_request_notification.wav"))
    let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "1", content: content, trigger: nil)
   ```